# Will many nrf24L01 radio modules running at the same time cause interference?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, communication, nrf24l01+

I am working on a battle bot type of project where their will be 4 transmitters communicating with 4 receivers attached to the robots in the 4 foot x 4 foot playing field. Are their any complications that will arise when trying to run many radio modules at the same time? Like relating to interference or noise? If so, what solutions or work-arounds exist for this problem?

Comment: `their` means `belonging to them` ... i think that you wanted to use `there`

Comment: my battle strategy would involve trying to jam the enemy's RF, blinding it with IR LEDs, and tasering it in case they didn't shield.

Answer (score 2):

According to [HowToMechatronics](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-wireless-communication-nrf24l01-tutorial/), the NRF24L01 module can use 125 different channels which gives a possibility to have a network of 125 independently working modems in one place. Each channel can have up to 6 addresses.

I believe that as long as you agree a channel allocation amongst competitors there shouldn’t be problems.

For more information on channel setting see [NRF24l01 Channel switching](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79452/nrf24l01-channel-switching)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Rishikesh, there is a great possibility they will have problems. Because I do not know the environment or what the hardware is configured I cannot properly answer your question without a lot more information. I can suggest Look here for some information: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/nrf24l01-transmission-problem/526158/3 Here is another link that will help: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/38005/nrf24l01-communication-is-interfered-by-wifi I hope this helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.